# Is there a special way to call videos when uploading to amplify hosting?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, video, hosting, create-react-app

I'm working on a create-react-app project, the project is supposed to show a background video on landing page.

It is working perfectly on localhost:3000 but when I upload to amplify hosting, video stop showing.

I already tried to call the same video directly from this url http://ormuxwater.com/MobterVideo.mp4 on the DOM by modifying it on developer console and it is still not showing anything, so my guess is that is not a folder file location problem

I also tried calling it from different places.
first try: import MobterVideo from `"../../assets/MobterVideo.mp4";`

```
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="{MobterVideo.mp4}" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
```

second try:

```
// calling it directly from public folder
<video playsinline="playsinline" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="/MobterVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
```

Is there something we need to take care for videos to work when uploading to aws amplify? 
console is not returning errors and I don't know what else to look

You can see working demo in https://mobter.mx

Answer (score 3):

You have to upload the video to an AWS S3 bucket (cloud hosting) and then you can src the file, that's the only way that worked for me; although I guess you could use a different cloud hosting service, but I guess it's probably better to us S3 if you're using Amplify. Here are the instruction on how to do it:

https://docs.sumerian.amazonaws.com/tutorials/create/beginner/s3-video/

You should only need steps 1 & 2

Answer (score 0):

in Rewrites and redirects you can add :

</^[^.]+$|.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|mp4|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/> /index.html 200 (Rewrite)

this will allow mp4 to be served by the website and other media type