# How can I get my background video working when hosted on AWS?

Tags: reactjs

This is my first post. I'm a newbie when it comes to developing. I hosted my first website (Portfolio page) the other day and I had one major problem. I have a background video that loops and plays in my hero section. Works properly on my local host, however does not work when hosted on my website using AWS Amplify. Can someone help how to get this working on my website? Thanks in advance

```
export const VideoBg = styled.video`
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
    background: #232a24;
`

import Video from '../../videos/video.mp4'

const HeroSection = () => {

 
    return (
        <HeroContainer id='home'>
            <HeroBg>
                <VideoBg autoPlay loop muted src={Video} type='video/mp4' />
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61972853/is-there-a-special-way-to-call-videos-when-uploading-to-amplify-hosting).
You should upload the video you want to display on was s3 bucket.